# Global jQuery `.click()`

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I would like to fire an event when *anything* on the page is clicked, and then process normally. For example a click would be fired, I would see if the target matched something, alert if it did, and then have the click event continue (no `preventDefault()`).

Comment: If you click something, it will match something - unless you really meant "match some specific thing"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    // e.target is the element which has been clicked.
});
```

This will handle all click events unless a handler prevents the event from bubbling up (by calling the *stopPropagation()* method of the *event* object).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").click(function (event) {
// Your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**3 options for you:**

This is how .live() in jquery works.  Everything bubbles to the top, and it matches the selector you set.
http://api.jquery.com/live/

A more efficient way to do it is using .delegate, or providing a context to .live() so you don't have to bubble to the top.
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

If you want to do it manually, bind 'click' to the document, and use .closest() to find the closest matching selector:
http://api.jquery.com/closest/

It's all the same concept, event delegation as mentioned already.